# Dimension of the union of a 4-dimensional and 3-dimensional simplex

Tags: geometry, simplex, simplicial-complex

Say I'm given two simplices: one is a 4-simplex and the other is a 3-simplex, and I've proven their intersection is non-empty. How do I now explain what the dimension of their union is?

I understand that it can never be higher than 4, and I'm trying to visualize the situation, but thats difficult in 4 dimensions.

I thought of a simpler example: the union of a 1-simplex and a 2-simplex (so let's say a line and a triangle), must have dimension 2, right?

Am I then correct in saying that the dimension of the union of a 3-simplex and a 4-simplex will be 4?

Comment: Yes, try thinking about it in terms of basis vector, it might become clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, by the definition, the dimension of a simplicial complex is defined as the maximal dimension of its faces.